# What is 'Modular shell disassociation from kernel'

Tags: web-application, injection, kernel

Under many difference resources (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection for one), there are some great tips to defend against code injection.

However, one of those is 'Modular shell disassociation from kernel' - but after quite a bit of Googling, this term doesn't seem to be defined anywhere - but every other site seems to copy and paste it as a defence mechanism for code injection flaws.

Can someone describe what 'Modular shell disassociation from kernel' actually means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your observations that this specific term is not well-explained and that a lot of sites seem to just parrot each other.

While i am by no means a linux dev, my best guess would be to look at the the unshare() syscall:

> unshare allows ... an ability to
>   disassociate parts of the context [such as
>   virtual memory and open files]

[Source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/unshare.txt)

> unshare can be used to implement polyinstantiated directories using
>   the kernel's per-process namespace mechanism. Polyinstantiated directories,
>   such as per-user and/or per-security context instance of /tmp, /var/tmp or
>   per-security context instance of a user's home directory, isolate user
>   processes when working with these directories. Using unshare, a PAM
>   module can easily setup a private namespace for a user at login.

Comment: I haven't really heard any other better answers, so I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: Glad to be the right answer by default :)